# count number of occurences before a certain date

Tags: sql, postgresql

base_table

```
  date      cust_id   review_score
2021-10-19  1              0
2021-08-06  1              7
2021-07-06  1              3
2021-04-06  1              4
2021-07-06  2              5
2021-04-06  2              6
```

Based on the table above, I would like to create a new column, how many reviews existed before the current review.

Expected output:

```
date      cust_id   review_score num_prior_reviews
2021-10-19  1              0              3 
2021-08-06  1              7              2
2021-07-06  1              3              1
2021-04-06  1              4              0
2021-07-06  2              5              1
2021-04-06  2              6              0
```

Explanation:
On 19 Oct 2021, customer ID has 3 reviews before that date (in April, in July and in August).
So far, I used `row_number() over (partition by cust_id order by date DESC) as rank`,
but not sure how to progress from there.

row_number() over (partition by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much have it...

```
    select date, cust_id, review_score, 
    row_number() over (partition by cust_id order by date asc) - 1 as num_prior_reviews
    from reviews
    order by cust_id, date desc
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use window function `count` or `row_number`:

```
select * , count(*) over (partition by cust_id order by date) -1 num_prior_reviews
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in this case, you can use self join.

```
SELECT k.*,COUNT(*) FROM dbo.kitap k 
INNER JOIN dbo.kitap k1 
ON k.cust_id = k1.cust_id 
WHERE k.date>=k1.date
GROUP BY k.date,k.cust_id,k.review_score
```